# XenServer 5.5 Error adding additional Server to Ressource Pool

Tags: xen, xenserver

I'm running Citrix XenServer 5.5 as a testsetup, with Openfiler providing Storage via NFS. I tried to setup a Ressource Pool to test Live migration but I'm unable to a my 2. Server to the Pool. 
It fails after about 10sec with the Error:

4/26/2010 2:54:52 PM Error: Adding server 'u-173-c047.XXX.XXX' to pool 'Portland' - Internal error: Stunnel.Stunnel_error("")

I'm kind of lost right now where to look whats causing this, and the Error is not really of any help. Are there logs availible somewhere besides in XenCenter, which might be helpful?

Any Ideas what is causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your openfiler NFS has it's access to allow both servers to write to the Shared Storage Repository.

You can ssh to the box that is the primary for your Resource Pool. Check in the log directory:
/var/log/

```
messages
secure
SMlog
xenstored-access.log
dmesg
```

Take a look in those logs and it might get you in the right direction.

Also is your hardware the same for each of your nodes in the pool?

Comment: Yeah hardware is exactly the same, but NFS might actually be the problem will check that tomorrow, thanks for the hint and also for the direction to the logs.